# JavaScript variable Objects

Tags: javascript

I am very much new to Javascript
please correct my code or suggest the best option

```
var myApp = {};

myApp.set = function(VAL) {
    myApp.id = VAL;    
}

myApp.get = function() {
    return myApp.id; 
}

function PageLoad() {
    var X = new myApp;
    var Y = new myApp;

    Y.set(20);
    X.set(10);

    alert(X.get());
    alert(Y.get());
}
```

It shows last assign value only i.e. 10 :(

Thanks in Advance 
Manoj

Comment: Are you sure that's your code as I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: myApp is not a constructor`.

Comment: I guess there is a typo, it should be `var X= new myApp()` (parenthesis)

Comment: This cannot be your actual code because this code does not run.  Please show us your actual code, otherwise this question needs to be closed as invalid.

Comment: @Pablo, no, the parentheses are not required, when used with [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

Comment: @NinaScholz Wow, years writing JS code without knowing that... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Manoj Chavanke Sir Please use this code

```
 function myApp(){
    }
    myApp.prototype.set = function(VAL) {
        this.id = VAL;    
    }

    myApp.prototype.get = function() {
        return this.id; 
    }

    function PageLoad() {
        var X = new myApp; console.log(X);
        var Y = new myApp; console.log(Y);

        Y.set(20);
        X.set(10);

        alert(X.get());
        alert(Y.get());
    }
    PageLoad();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Karan,
Could you please help me to write same code Using Object Literal Notation??

Answer (score 0):

I think You override the value myApp.id = VAL;

try this code

```js
 var myApp = [];
myApp.set = function(VAL) {
    myApp.push({id : VAL});
}
```

instate of

```js
var myApp = {};

myApp.set = function(VAL) {
    myApp.id = VAL;    
}
```

Because the key is a **unique** you can't use twice.